# Why do I get this error when inserting a record: duplicate value for a record with unique key

Tags: .net, sql, informix

Let me explain more...

When inserting a record into an informix db table, if I specify a value for one of the columns, no matter what the value, it will always throw the below error (this little tidbit of info is golden and took me a while to figure out). The column is a char (4). There is no unique key index on the field that I can tell (using squirrel).  There are many other columns in the table I'm setting the value on, but don't have this problem.

```
ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]ISAM error:  duplicate value for a record with unique key.
```

or

```
Error: Could not insert new row - duplicate value in a UNIQUE INDEX column.
```

There must be something with the table schema that I'm missing...  Can anyone point me in the right direction where and how to find this "supposed" unique key it's failing on (preferably using squirrel)?  I've already looked at the object window under the Primary Key tab and Indexes tab and the column is not listed in either one.

I can give a more info about the table schema according to squirrel:
There are no primary keys, there are 10 indexes, non of which are tied to the column that's having the problem. Of the 10 indexes only 1 is a unique index.

Comment: You need to look at the indexs on the table that you are tring to INSERT to. One (or More) of those indexes specify a column (or set of columns) that may only contain any value once. The classic example of this kind of unique index is the Primary Key on the table. My first guess is that you are inserting a row with a PK value that already exists in the table - This is the most frequent reason for this error.

Comment: Does the table havea trigger on it? Perhaps ther error is coming from actions happening in a trigger.

Comment: Can you provide the table details?  I'm not familiar with Informix, but it looks like (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284187/informix-equivalent-to-mysqls-show-create-table) there's a "dbschema" command line tool.

Comment: @HLGEM - Good point about the trigger, I'll see if I can figure out how to see them in informix.

Comment: @Jon Informix is hosted on a unix box - not sure if there's a tool to see schema there.

Comment: @goku_da_master. Usually there is a command line tool on that unix box that can retrieve all the information about a table, including the triggers, indexes and constraints: dbschema -d DATABASENAME -t TABLENAME

Comment: `dbschema -d dbname -t tablename`, assuming INFORMIX environment variables (INFORMIXDIR, ONCONFIG, possibly DB_LOCALE, INFORMIXSQLHOSTS) set properly.

Comment: after digging further, indeed it was a trigger - a trigger on a child table.  Meaning, the trigger on the parent table affected a child table, and there was a trigger on the child table that was causing this error.  @HLGEM Can you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These problems are often caused by a trigger. I woudl check to see if there are triggers that might be causeing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> If I specify a value for one of the columns, no matter what the value, it will always throw the [-239 / -100] error.

Remember, when you insert into a table, you insert entire rows.  Even if you specify a value for only one of the columns, a default value (often NULL) is inserted into the other columns.

*(There's also a chance I'm misinterpreting what you mean; you might be saying that if you specify values for all columns except one specific one, the INSERT works; if you specify a value for the specific column too, the INSERT always fails.  You might need to run `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT problem_column) FROM <table>` to help determine the trouble.)*

> There are no primary keys.  There are 10 indexes, none of which are tied to the column that's having the problem. Of the 10 indexes only 1 is a unique index.

You have a unique index (which is de facto the primary key, even though it is not declared as the primary key).  If you're not specifying the value for that column in your INSERT statement, then it is likely that NULL is being inserted, and you can only have one row in the table with NULL in that column.  Informix does not support 'UNIQUE UNLESS NULL'.

Note that 10 indexes on a table is a large number; I'd need some convincing that more than about 3 of them pull their weight, unless they are indexes on foreign key columns.

To get any more help, you will need to post:

1. The schema of the table (or a suitable subset of the schema, with an indication of how many columns are missing).
2. The INSERT statement that you're executing.